# Unable to use pandas module in centos

Tags: python, pandas, centos, installation

In centos I did `pip install pandas`. Everything looked successful.

However when I `import pandas` I get:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Not sure how to fix. Also sys.modules is also showing no pandas.

Comment: You wouldn't expect to see an entry in `sys.modules` until the module had been successfully imported (which it clearly wasn't here)

Comment: `$ pip freeze` will list the installed packages. Are you using a virtualenv? If not, you really should consider it. That will fix most python installation based issues. https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/